# Multiplication table with identity and order

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

[image: 1]]

This seems relatively easy, however I do not understand what is meant by the order of $x$ for each $x\in G\setminus\{3\}$ is equal to $2$. Can someone point me in the right direction? Clearly $G\setminus\{3\}=\{1,2,4\}$ but where can I go from here

Comment: If $3$ is the identity element, and the order of $1$ is $2$, what is $1^2$?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see 1^2=3. I misinterpreted the Order of x as being the number of elements in some sort of subset x. Silly mistake, thank you

Comment: I suspect you're thrown off by thinking that the identity element "ought" to be $1$.  But it's not.  We're told it's $3$.  So since the "order" of an element in a group is the smallest power that's equal to the identity (whatever the group identity happens to be), what do we know?

Comment: If you know that  there are exactly two groups (up to isomorphism) of order $4$ and what they are, then this question is easy to answer. Are you allowed to use this information?

Comment: " I misinterpreted the Order of x as being the number of elements in some sort of subset x. Silly mistake"  It's not silly, not a mistake.  It's simple not recognizing a definition.  If you know the definition I fully trust this will be straight forward.  (and in a way it *is* the number of elements in a subset! If the order of $a$ is $5$ then the subset $\{e,a, a*a, a*a*a, a*a*a*a\}$ forms a subgroup!  And it has.... 5 elements.)

Comment: [And $\{1,3\},*:1*1=3;1*3=1;3*1=1;3*3=3$, is a subgroup with 2 elements.]

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

If the order of each $x$ (excluding $3$ which is the identity) is equal to $2$ then what do you get when you multiply $x$ with itself?

> you of course get the identity element which is $3$ in your case, this way you can fill the diagonal in your table

How to fill the rest of the table?

Since all grouptables a so called *latin squares* so you have to have each element once in each row and column, a sort of a sudoku.

You need to have a $2$ and a $4$ for somewhere in the first row

> $2$ cannot be in the first row second column since this would mean that $1$ is the identity, so the first row has elements $3,4,1,2$ of course in this order from left to right

The rest fills itself

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

"order" mean how many times you must operate an element with itself to get the identity.

$a^k = a*a*a*...... *a$.  If $a^k =e$ and $k$ is the smallest power so that is true, that is called the "order of $a$"[1].  In this group $a^2 = e =3$ always. (except maybe for $3$ where $3=3$.  But $3*3 = 3$ so.. yes, $3^2 = 3$....)

So you have

$\begin{array}*&|1&2&3&4\\
-&-&-&-&-\\
1&|3&?&1&?\\
2&|?&3&2&?\\
3&|1&2&3&4\\
4&|?&?&4&3\\
\end{array}$

=====

[1] One can prove for a finite group that $a^k = e$ must exist.  For an infinite group (such as $\mathbb Z, +$) it doesn't have to.  In that case we say something has infinite order.

In $\mathbb Z, +$ the number $1$ has infinite order because $1+1+1+.....$ will never equal $0$.

In $\mathbb Z_6, +$ then $1$ has order $6$ because $1+1+1+1+1+1 = 0$.  ANd $2$ has order $3$ because $2+2+2 = 0$.  And $3$ has order $2$ because $3+3 = 0$.  And $4$ has order $3$ because $4+4+4= 0$.  $5$ has order $6$ because $5+5+5+5+5+5 = 6$ and $0$ has order $1$ because $0 = 0$.

The identity $e$ *always* has order $1$.

===

Post script.  Other than labeling there are $2$ groups with $4$ elements.  There are those in which one of the elements is such that $a * a =b \ne e$ and $a *a*a = c\ne e$ but $a*a*a*a = e$. (If you complete this you will get there is only one possible group.)  And the other is where all of the elements are that $a * a = e; b*b=e; c*c=e$.  If you complete this (as you are doing above) you will get that there is only one possible group.